# Podem analisar minha calculadora em C e me ajudar a finalizar o projeto

Tags: c

```html
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
 float n1=0;
 char operacao;
 float n2=0;
 printf("*CALCULADORA\n");
 printf("n1:");
 scanf("%f", & n1);
 printf("operacao:");
 scanf("%c", operacao);
 printf("n2:");
 scanf("%f", n2);
 // operacao de adicao
 switch(operacao){
  case '+':
   printf("R:%f+%f=%f\n", n1, n2, n1+n2);
   break;
   //operacao de subtracao
   switch(operacao){
  case '-':
   printf("R:%f-%f=%f\n", n1, n2, n1-n2);
   break;
  }//operacao de multiplicao
   switch(operacao){
  case '*':
   printf("R:%f*%f=%f\n", n1, n2, n1*n2);
   break;
  }//operacao de divisão
  case '/':
  if(n2==0){
   printf("ne");
  }else{
   printf("R:%f/%f=%f\n", n1, n2, n1/n2);
  }  
 break;
 default:
  printf("operacao inv");
  return 0;
 }
 
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]porque ficou estático, porque nao apareceu n2. me ajudem a concluir, por favor

Answer (score 2):

Aqui: scanf("%c", operacao); faltou o & antes da variável operacao; idem em: scanf("%f", n2);.
Não tem sentido estes switch antes de cada case. Reveja a sintaxe do comando switch/case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
    float n1=0;
    char operacao;
    float n2=0;
    printf("*CALCULADORA\n");
    printf("n1:");
    scanf("%f", &n1);
    printf("operacao:");
    scanf("%c", &operacao);
    printf("n2:");
    scanf("%f", &n2);
    // operacao de adicao
    switch(operacao){
        case '+':
            printf("R:%f+%f=%f\n", n1, n2, n1+n2);
            break;
            //operacao de subtracao
        case '-':
            printf("R:%f-%f=%f\n", n1, n2, n1-n2);
            break;
            //operacao de multiplicao
        case '*':
            printf("R:%f*%f=%f\n", n1, n2, n1*n2);
            break;
            //operacao de divisão
        case '/':
            if(n2==0){
                printf("ne");
            }else{
                printf("R:%f/%f=%f\n", n1, n2, n1/n2);
            }       
            break;
        default:
            printf("operacao inv");
    }
    return 0;
}
```